# Restrict report parameter to a certain length

Tags: java, validation, birt

In a BIRT report I created a report parameter for entering "Year" value. I want to restrict 4 digits on that input field. How can I do that? User should type only four digit in that field. Is any configuration or script available to achieve this?

Comment: Please add the code you already have.

Comment: if you are using html for input field then restrict user by validation.

Comment: i am not using html page for user input.in birt there is already option to create report parameter(through gui)..It will come as Input parameter.there i didnt see any option to set maxlength

Answer (score 1):

You can't restrict the length of a textbox-entered value in BIRT.

You *could* set the parameter display type to be List Box and specify the available values for the year, either as a static list of values entered in the Edit Parameter dialog or as a dynamic set of values retrieved from a dataset.

Comment: is any way,this can implement using script??

Comment: @vmb: "this" what? The static list of values? The dynamic set of values retrieved from a dataset? Something else?

Comment: what i meant is whether is it  possible to restricting length through scripting??

Comment: There is a `validate` script event in BIRT that you could use to *reject* entries longer than 4 characters - however, you cannot customise the rejection message; it will always be of the form `"Report generation failed. Cause: The validation for parameter "Year" fails"`.

Comment: @vmb: Beyond rejecting entries longer than 4 characters using the `validate` script event - no, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a script for the `validate` event of your parameter. It must return true or false if its value will be correct or not. In your case:

```
if (BirtStr.charLength(params["Year"].value) == 4)
    true;
else
    false;
```